# Bonding in MOF-5

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, coordination-compounds, molecular-structure

I came up with this problem today and I can't find the answer elsewhere:

How does the oxygen atom bond to the four zinc atoms? To be more specific, what would be the molecular orbital diagram for the Zn4O cluster[image: MOF-5 structure]

Does this have an obvious answer?

Comment: I guess my question to you is why not? An oxygen in liquid water can be coordinated simultaneously to up to four hydrogens. Isn't this case exactly analogous?

Comment: Does it have an obvious answer? I have no experience of these types of clusters but I strongly suspect the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zhe suggested -- it's just a tetrahedral bonding-interaction of oxygen. In the case of $\ce{H2O}$, oxygen has two lone pairs and two bonds to $\ce{H}$; in $\ce{[OZn4]^{6+}}$, those lone pairs are interacting with Zn atoms (strongly, because the $\ce{Zn}$ atoms bear a +2 charge).

Per the [MOF-5 $\ce{H2}$ storage paper](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/300/5622/1127.full):

> ...inorganic $\ce{[OZn4]^{6+}}$ groups are joined to an octahedral array of
>   $\ce{[O2C-C6H4-CO2]^{2–}}$ (1,4-benzenedicarboxylate, BDC) groups to form a
>   robust and highly porous cubic framework.

Per the [original synthesis](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v402/n6759/full/402276a0.html):

> A small amount of hydrogen peroxide was added to the reaction mixture
>   in order to facilitate the formation of $\ce{O^{2-}}$ expected at the centre of
>   the secondary building unit.

Thus the central oxygen has a full octet, able to supply 2 electrons to each $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ in the coordination complex.